# What is the name of this Taekwondo black belt bo form?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, weapons, forms, bo-staff

I asked at the school and no one knows the name. We call it the **Advanced Bo Form**. This form was brought over from the previous school before our current Grand Master took over. Only a hand full of us know this form.

**Does anyone know the name of this form?** and if so, is this the traditional version?

**UPDATE:** Video of the form [Advanced Bo Form - Kangs MMA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-Xv66pP_kw)

**UPDATE 2:** I named this form Bo Bonneung 본능 meaning Instinct. A video with the proper pace for the form: [Bo Bonneung 본능 "Instinct" - Kang MMA](https://www.facebook.com/kangsmma/videos/t.38008428/190620764706438/?type=3&theater)

Comment: Yes, please post the video.

Comment: Ok, I will make one today during/after class and post it. Also, I'm not sure if all the moves are from the original form but a good percentage of it is.

Comment: As Andy Jeffries states, Kukkiwon does not recognize any official weapons forms. ATA has 3 different jangh bong forms, short range, long range and windstaff. I know a WTF school locally that has two different staff forms, which is different than the WTF school I attended in Nevada.

Comment: That's very interesting. I looked up some of the Jangh Bong forms but they are very different than the forms we do at the school. I tried writing up a description of the form but it was just confusing. I guess it will require me posting the video to ID this form.

Comment: Is it possible that the form is named different? The only "chumbi" form I found was an introductory one by Westerfield TKD club, but a few that suggested it was a misspelling of "choon be", or the ready command.

Comment: It's not a Chumbi form. I was only trying to describe what you do to get to Chumbi before you start the form.

Comment: @JohnP I have added the video :) Sorry it took so long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is a "traditional taekwondo black belt bo form".

The Kukkiwon (at the Foreign Taekwondo Master Training Course in 2013) says there are no weapons in Taekwondo, but some schools add them to boost their curriculum.

I had a quick look in General Choi's encyclopaedias (the 1965 one and the multi-volume set) and can't find any references to weapon training except for defending against attackers that have weapons.

You may be best asking your instructor or another student for the name of this, as it may be specific to your school.

Comment: Thank you for the response Andy, great information. I asked at the school and no one knows the name. This form was brought over from the previous school before our current Grand Master took over. Only a hand full of us know the form.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional TKD had no "Bo" form. 
The traditional Korean systems had very few weapons in them at all. They later began to adopt the weapons systems of surrounding nations like Japan and China. They did adopt the 6' staff, but it is called a "joong bong". In fact the Japanese Kata that were adopted and transformed into "TKD" forms were generally never given their own names but called "Joong Bong Hyung I" or "Joong Bong Hyung 2". Which is like saying "staff form 1"....etc.

NOTE: These adaptations from other systems are fairly modern and aren't a part of "Traditional" TKD. The arts that first began to incorporate them were Kook Sul Won, Hwarang Do, Mu Sul and Hapkido..........all of which are reinterpretations of traditions and arts from other nations, not Korea. They are adopted cousins to TKD.